# how to do attachments for each sql record in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, attachment

I am developing a desktop application in c# & sql 2005. With candidate data entry form I want to provide option to attach required documents(in pdf format) wid data. Kindly let me know the best method. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You want to store those files in the database?

Comment: Thanks for reply.Not actually in database but on server so that i can access them through my desktop application.

Comment: Is it posible you can upgrade to Sql server 2008? http://lopataru.wordpress.com/2009/03/20/document-management-with-sql-server/

Comment: No i cant pl provide me d solution with sql 2005.

Comment: can ny1 tell me if i use 'web reference service' to upload file through desktop application will it work?

Answer (score 1):

Well then unfortunately you have to either manage the file storage yourself using the servers file system, or you could store it in the db itself (IT WILL GET BLOATED!!!)

See sql server 2005 file storage

[How To: Encrypt and Manage Documents with SQL Server 2005](https://web.archive.org/web/20210121191501/http://geekswithblogs.net/chrisfalter/archive/2008/05/08/encrypt-documents-with-sql-server.aspx)

OK, then for file management

see this example

[File Manager Component](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3952/File-Manager-Component)

Comment: preferably i dont want to store files on sql server can u pl explore on second method.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a table that will contain the filename and server path for the file to be attached, then create a method to copy the attached file to the server location and store the relivant information (name and path) in the table.  Use other methods to retrive the file from the server location when requested.  Simple.

I personaly prefer to store the documents as BLOBs since server file structures and paths can change over time.

Comment: Thank you Bert for ur reply.

As this is my first project & i m beginner in programming can u pl let me know it in detail.

Thanking u..